Prove that $L(X) \subseteq L(X \cup Y)$.
Given that $L(X)$ is a subspace generated by $X$, any vector in $L(X)$ is a linear combination of the vectors in $X$. That is: $$v=L(X)\rightarrow v=\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_i x_i: (x_i\in X, a_i \in R,  \forall i=1,..,m).$$ Therefore $x_i\in X$, we can deduce that if $( X \subset X )$, then $( X \subset X \cup Y )$, such that each vector in ( $L(X)$ ) can be expressed as a linear combination in $( X \cup Y )$, that is:$$(X\cup Y)\subset L(X) \rightarrow  L(X\cup Y) =\sum_{i=1}^{t}a_{i} x_i:(x_i\in (X\cup Y), a_i\in R,
\forall i=1,..,t).$$So that $$=\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{i} x_i + \sum_{i=n+1}^{t}a_{i} x_i$$Given that the first term belongs to $L(X)$ , we deduce that the other term is from $L(Y)$, therefore $L(X)\subseteq L(X \cup Y)$

Are $X$ and $Y$ assumed to be finite here? That is, are you assuming $X = {x_1, \ldots, x_m}$ and $X \cup Y = {x_1, \ldots, x_m, x_{m+1}, \ldots, x_t}$? Or are you using the definition of $L(X)$ where $X$ may be infinite, i.e.$$L(X) = \left{\sum_{i=1}^m a_i x_i : m \in \Bbb{N}, {x_1, \ldots, x_m} \subseteq X, {a_1, \ldots, a_m} \subseteq \Bbb{R}\right}?$$

@TheoBendit Sorry, I'm new to proofs. I assumed it was finite because I didn't know how to approach the exercise :c

No worries! I guessed that this was probably the case, but without a specific definition of $X$ as ${x_1, \ldots, x_m}$, I couldn't be totally sure.

It appears to me that you are proving something different: that $L(X) + L(Y) \subseteq L(X \cup Y)$. This is true, and in fact, we can put equality there. But, this is not the same as showing $L(X) \subseteq L(X \cup Y)$. To do that, you need to show that, for any $v \in L(X)$, you also have $v \in L(X \cup Y)$.
From your assumption that $v \in L(X)$, you can assume that you have scalars $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_m$ (in $\Bbb{R}$, but this works over any field) such that $v = \sum_{i=1}^m a_i x_i$. That is, you are given scalars $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_m$.
You then need to show $v \in L(X \cup Y)$. So, you need to find scalars $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_t$ such that $v = \sum_{i=1}^t b_i x_i$. That is, you need to write, explicitly, what each $b_i$ is in terms of $a_1, \ldots, a_m$. Once you can find $b_1, \ldots, b_t$ so that $\sum_{i=1}^t b_i x_i$ simplifies to $v$, then the proof is done.
Your observation about the sum splitting is helpful here: we can split the task to finding $b_1, \ldots, b_m$ and $b_{m+1}, \ldots, b_t$ such that
$$v = \sum_{i=1}^m b_i x_i + \sum_{i=m+1}^t b_i x_i.$$
We already know $v = \sum_{i=1}^m b_i x_i$, so we could just let $b_i := a_i$ for $i = 1, \ldots, m$, and make the second sum disappear by letting $b_i = 0$ for $i = m+1, \ldots, t$. That is, we can write:
$$v = \sum_{i=1}^m a_i x_i + \sum_{i=m+1}^t 0 x_i,$$
which puts $v \in L(X \cup Y)$.
That's the scratch proof. If I were going to turn it into a complete proof, I would write it like so:

Suppose $X = \{x_1, \ldots, x_m\}$. Given any finite subset $Y$ of the vector space, we have $X \subseteq X \cup Y$, so $X \cup Y$ must take the form
$$X \cup Y = \{x_1, \ldots, x_m, x_{m+1}, \ldots, x_t\}.$$
Further, suppose $x \in L(X)$. Then, there exist $a_1, \ldots, a_m \in \Bbb{R}$ such that
$$v = \sum_{i=1}^m a_i x_i.$$
Then,
$$v = \sum_{i=1}^m a_i x_i + \sum_{i=m+1}^t 0 x_i \in L(X \cup Y).$$
Thus, $L(X) \subseteq L(X \cup Y)$.

That's all I'd write.
Now, in the spirit of proof-writing, let me give you some stylistic pointers:

You seem to have this set $X$ and introduced $x_1, \ldots, x_m$ without connecting the two explicitly. Introducing the individual elements of $X$ is an important step, but you need to do it properly. You should say, somewhere early on, that $X = \{x_1, \ldots, x_m\}$, rather than getting the reader to guess this connection. You should also do the same with $Y$.

Writing $v = L(X)$ is confusing. The left hand side appears to be a vector, while the right hand side is a set of vectors. They are not the same. You should write $v \in L(X)$ instead, to denote $v$ is an element of the set $L(X)$.

Similar to the previous point, you write:
$$v=\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_i x_i: (x_i\in X, a_i \in R,  \forall i=1,..,m).$$
then
$$L(X\cup Y) =\sum_{i=1}^{t}a_{i} x_i:(x_i\in (X\cup Y), a_i\in R,
\forall i=1,..,t).$$
This is also a little confusing. The first one seems to say that the specific vector $v$ has the form $\sum_{i=1}^m a_i x_i$ for some $x_i \in X$, and $a_i \in \Bbb{R}$, for $i = 1, \ldots, m$. The second one seems to be writing $L(X \cup Y)$ in a similar way, but now it defines a set, not just a single vector. Try to delineate between sets of vectors and the vectors they contain.

"Therefore $x_i \in X$, we can deduce that if $(X\subset X)$, then $(X \subset X \cup Y)$" Two points. First, it's weird that you seem to be concluding that $x_i \in X$, rather than asserting it. Second, there's probably no need to mention that $X\subset X$, as justification for saying $X \subseteq X \cup Y$. Indeed, $X \subseteq X \cup Y$ needs no justification here; this is presumably a linear algebra course, not an elementary set theory course.

On this point, I would stick to either $\subset$ or $\subseteq$ to denote subset relations with possible equality. Some authors use $\subseteq$ to denote this, and $\subset$ to denote proper subsets (making $X \subset X$ false). Other authors use $\subset$ to denote non-strict subsets, while $\subsetneq$ to denote strict subsets. By writing both $\subset$ or $\subseteq$ in your proof, it suggests that you're writing in the first style, which, again, would make the assertion $X \subset X$ false. You clearly mean non-strict subsets whenever you use either notation, so stick with one or the other.

Generally, speaking, I would advise fewer symbols. You don't quite fall into the common trap of over-using symbols as a way of making things more "formal", but you don't quite avoid it either. Rather than writing
$$v\in L(X)\implies v=\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_i x_i: (x_i\in X, a_i \in R,  \forall i=1,..,m),$$
I would write "Because $v \in L(X)$, there exist $a_1, \ldots, a_m \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $v=\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_i x_i$". (Note I didn't introduce the fact that $x_i \in X$ here; see my first point.) By writing it out with words, I think it's more human-readable. Also, the quantification of the $a_i$s becomes clearer: it's true that $v=\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_i x_i$ for some $a_i$s, not for all $a_i$s, or indeed, for some specific $a_i$s that were supposed to be introduced earlier, but were not, for whatever reason.


Sorry for the info overload. I hope this helps. Please feel free to ask me in the comments below if you want clarification.
